# Remove directory from glob() results

Tags: php

I'm using the following PHP snippett to display all the pdf in a directory.  How do I alter this code to still specify the directory BUT only display the filename?

```
foreach (glob("directory/sub-directory/sub-subdirectory/*.pdf") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename <BR>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
$shortname = basename($filename);
echo "$shortname <BR />\n";
```

You would be making use of the [basename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function.

Comment: You can add the second parameter as `'.pdf'` if you don't want to display the extension as well.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks!  Man I love PHP!

Comment: It's a pretty demented programming language, but I enjoy it also.